# Unable to access App Engine Application running in Android Studio using Android Device Application in LAN

Tags: android, android-studio, google-app-engine

1. I am running Google App Engine application in Android Studio.
2. Installing Android Application to my Android Device from the same Android Studio.
3. appengine task configuration in build.gradle of GAE application is as follows:

   ```
   appengine {
       downloadSdk = true
       jvmFlags = ["-Ddatastore.backing_store=$localDbPath"]
       httpPort = 8888
       httpAddress = "0.0.0.0"
   }
   ```
4. Connecting both devices ("Laptop - which running Android Studio" and "Mobile which running Android Application") in the same LAN connection.
5. My Android Application makes a request to the AppEngine application which running on Android Studio.
6. As a result of the above call I'm getting "Connection timeout" error.
7. If run the App Engine application in Eclipse instead of Android Studio then Android Device Application is able to make a successful to connection to GAE Application.
8. One more thing I tried is configuring Laptop IP Address in httpAddress like `***.***.*.*`. Still getting the connection timeout error.

What are the settings missing in Android Studio ?

Comment: so you want your Android App to call your Google App Engine Application which is running on your local machine? Can you please post how your Android App makes the request?

Comment: Can you check the arguments of the devserver process when launched through `Eclipse` (OK according to statement #7) vs. `Android Studio` (not OK)?

Answer (score 5):

I got the same Connection timeout error while running in Android Studio while its not happening in Eclipse.

Below are the solutions which i have followed to overcome such issue

**Solution 1:**

> Run your Android Studio App in Emulator instead of Mobile Physical
>   device

This will reduce the connection timeout error

**Solution 2:**

> Android Manifest file Internet permission updating and connecting
>   with Local internet Wifi

**Solution 3:**

```
Check your gradle version and its followed the below in Android Studio,    
 [https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-gradle][1]

Check your environment by satisfying the google norms 
 [https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments][1]
```

Comment: Solution 1: Testing with Emulator worked for me as a workaround for temporary testing. But unable test with actual device.

Solution 2 wont work for me. Since in my case it is "Connection timeout" not "Network permission denied" error.